# Запрос, при наличии unique constraint, выдаёт ошибку ORA-01779: нельзя изменить столбец, кот.отображает non key-preserved таблицу

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

В таблице `user1.btable` заведён *unique constraint* на 4 поля: `c, d, e, f`.

Запрос

```
update (select a.bid a$bid, b.bid b$bid
       from user1.atable a
       join user1.btable b
         on a.c = b.c
        and a.d = b.d
        and a.e = b.e
        and b.f = 0)
set a$bid = b$bid;
```

выдаёт ошибку

> ORA-01779: нельзя изменить столбец, кот.отображает non key-preserved таблицу

Почему? Ведь обычно такая ошибка возникает по следующей причине

> Ораклу надо уникально идентифицировать запись которую надо поменять. А для этого подзапрос должен использовать все столбцы в уникальном ключе. Кроме того у вас в первом случае может возникнуть проблема с тем, что для одной записи из таблицы A будет выбрано несколько строк из балицы B и тогда ораклу будет не ясно а из какой из записей B взять bid *- [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541927/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b8-unique-constraint-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-ora-01779-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c#comment686571_541927)*

А если в таблицу `user1.atable` добавить поле `f`, и изменить условие соединения на

```
     on a.c = b.c
    and a.d = b.d
    and a.e = b.e
    and b.f = a.f
```

запрос ошибки не выдаёт.

Выдача `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION`

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
>      PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
>      CORE   11.2.0.1.0  Production
>      TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
>      NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: Ну собственно по тому, как и написано в тексте ошибки. Ораклу надо уникально идентифицировать запись которую надо поменять. А для этого подзапрос должен использовать все столбцы в уникальном ключе. Кроме того у вас в первом случае может возникнуть проблема с тем, что для одной записи из таблицы A будет выбрано несколько строк из балицы B и тогда ораклу будет не ясно а из какой из записей B взять bid

Comment: @Mike, 1) уникально идентифицировать это как? в таблице atable нет индексов по этим полям, а значит как в первом так и во втором запросе может быть выбрано несколько строк atable на одну btable. 2) Несколько строк из B не может быть выдано на одну A в обоих запросах, т.к. я в условии соединения указываю значения для каждого из полей unique constraint

Comment: Невнимательно прочитал, мне показалось у вас unique на первую таблицу. А просто условия a.f=b.f не достаточно, обязательно включать f в список выборки что бы оно сработало ?

Comment: условия a.f=b.f  достаточно, просто изначально в таблице atable нет такого поля, его приходится добавлять, чтобы обойти проблему. И хочется узнать ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Да, загадка. могу только предложить переписать запрос в виде `update user1.atable a
   set bid=(select nvl(max(b.bid),a.bid) from user1.btable b
       where a.c = b.c and a.d = b.d and a.e = b.e and b.f = 0)
`

Comment: Тема освещалась на sql.ru - http://www.sql.ru/forum/72570/ora-01779-cannot-modify-a-column-which-maps-to-a-non-key-preserved-table и http://www.sql.ru/forum/847553/off-update-mnozhestva-poley-iz-podzaprosa?hl=bypass_ujvc

Comment: @AK, по ссылкам не нашёл ничего по существу вопроса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В описанной Вами схеме все должно работать создал подобную тестовую схему:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLEA(  
  "C" VARCHAR2(10), 
  "D" VARCHAR2(10), 
  "E" VARCHAR2(10), 
  "F" VARCHAR2(10), 
  "BID" VARCHAR2(10));

CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLEB(
  "C" VARCHAR2(10), 
  "D" VARCHAR2(10), 
  "E" VARCHAR2(10), 
  "F" VARCHAR2(10), 
  "BID" VARCHAR2(10));

ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLEB
  add constraint CONSTR unique (C, D, E, F)
  using index;
```

И запрос (который Вы указывали в вопросе) на ней работает правильно, если есть constraint, но если его нет то выбрасывается исключение `ORA-01779`.

Что бы избежать появление ошибки попробуйте следующий запрос:

```
update test_tablea 
set bid = 
   (select b.bid
    from   test_tableb b
    where  test_tablea.c = b.c
    and    test_tablea.d = b.d
    and    test_tablea.e = b.e
    and    b.f = 0)
where exists(
    select b.bid
    from   test_tableb b
    where  test_tablea.c = b.c
    and    test_tablea.d = b.d
    and    test_tablea.e = b.e
    and    b.f = 0)
```

или его аналог с nvl предложенный в комментариях, но тогда у Вас будет лишние update(ы).

---

После проверки на разных версиях БД удалось установить следующее join update НЕ заработал на Oracle версий:

- Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0,
- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0.

Работает на:

- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0,
- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0,
- Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0.

Comment: выполнил ваш скрипт вверху. Потом запрос из своего вопроса. Та же ошибка. Какая у вас версия Oracle? свою добавил в вопрос

Comment: @3per, я тестировал на Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production.

Comment: Можем ли мы с Вами принять решение, что на лицо ошибка устранённая в более поздних версиях?

Comment: @3per, я сейчас поищу Вашу версию и попробую на ней!

Comment: @3per, проверил, Вы были правы на более новых версиях работает на старых нет.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу Mikhailov Valentine. На 10-ке запрос не работает, а на  SE 11.2.0.3.0 - работает. Судя по всему, в более новой версии при разборе запроса допускаются некоторые классы выражений, помимо прямых отсылок к полям базовой таблицы. Так, для простых выражений, вычисляемых на этапе разбора, и в итоге порождающих константу, запрос срабатывает: `b.f = 0` или `case when 0 is null then 0 else 0 end`. Но если это выражение содержит отсылки к другим полям, то не сработает: `b.f = a.f - a.f`, `case when a.f is null then a.f else a.f end`

Работает для условия `b.f = a.f`, но при этом не работает для условий: `b.f = a.f + 0`, `b.f = nvl(a.f, 0)`